# In eloquent : How to get a model that has the count of a related model exactly n with a condition?

Tags: laravel, count, eloquent, one-to-many, wherehas

In eloquent : How to get related a model where count of related models with a condition is is exactly n?

Here is over simplification of the problem that I am facing:-

There are multiple courses in database.
One course has many students.

I need to get courses with exactly 20 female students.
So, I need to do both.
Check that count of number of students is 20.
And check the condition that they are female.

Now I can either use "wherehas" which does not let me count related students. In fact it only checks if there is at least one female student.

```
Course
    ::whereHas('students',function($q){
        $q->where('gender','Female');
    })
    ->get()
;
```

Or I can use "has" which lets me count the related students but does not let me check if they are female or not.

```
Course
    ::has('students','=','20')
    ->get()
;
```

I need something that allows me to do both checking the count of students and checking that they are all female. Something like this is needed:-

```
// NOT ALLOWED IN ELOQUENT
Course
    ::has('students','=','20',function($q){
        $q->where('gender','Female');
    })
    ->get()
;
```

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) Documentation you can do something like this:

```php
Course
    ::whereHas('students',function($q){
        $q->where('gender','Female');
    }, '=', 20)
    ->get()
```